# How to Create a JQuery Container from a Mixture of DOM Elements and Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some DOM objects and object selectors.  Is there a way in JQuery to select the mixed set of both?  The following is what I have attempted:

```
// Note that in the real code, I don't know how el1 and el2 were obtained.
// They may have associated id fields, or they may not.
let el1 = document.getElementById('id1');
let el2 = $('#container > div > span').get();
let groupSelector = $([el1, el2, '#id3, div > span']);
```

I know that if all the elements had ids, or if I knew the original selectors, I could simply concatenate those into a comma-separated list.  However, not all of these elements have ids, and I don't know the original selectors.  How can I create a single JQuery container that includes the items indicated in the example code?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment by @Taplar:

```
let groupSelector = $('#id3, div > span').add([el1, el2]);
```